# Idk why this function doesnt work [react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i try edit my event-item and when i click to save button appears a new event...
n firebase, a new unidentified object is created in `calendar/${user?.uid} instead of editing the "text" field that is after the event id.

Do you know how to fix it?

Deleting items works fine. The edit button also passes the correct id

I spread my hands, I don't know how to deal with it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useEventApi } from "./hooks/useEvent";

export default function CalendarEvents() {
  const { getEvents, updateEvent, removeEvent } = useEventApi();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [editedText, setEditedText] = useState("");

  const fetchEvents = async () => {
    const eventList = await getEvents();
    setEvents(eventList);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);

  const handleEditEvent = (event) => {
    setEditedText(event.text);
    console.log("Edit event with key:", event.key);
  };
  
  const handleSaveEvent = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    if (editedText !== "") {
      await updateEvent(event.key, editedText);
      fetchEvents();
      setEditedText("");
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteEvent = async (event) => {
    try {
      await removeEvent(event.key);
      fetchEvents();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error removing events:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="calendar-events-container">
      <div className="calendar-form">
        <form onSubmit={handleSaveEvent}>
          <input
            placeholder="Wydarzenie"
            type="text"
            value={editedText}
            onChange={(e) => setEditedText(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
          <button className="add-btn" type="submit">
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="calendar-list-container">
        <h3>Events:</h3>
        {events.map((event) => (
          <div key={event.key} className="calendar-list-item">
            <span className="event-list-title">{event.text}</span>
            <button className="edit-btn" onClick={() => handleEditEvent(event)}>
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
            </button>
            <button className="delete-btn" onClick={() => handleDeleteEvent(event)}>
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/rules-of-hooks */
import { push, ref, update, remove, get } from 'firebase/database';
import { db, auth } from '../../../firebase';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';

export const useEventApi = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const path = `calendar/${user?.uid}`;

  const getEvents = async () => {
    const eventsSnapshot = await get(ref(db, path));
    const eventsObject = eventsSnapshot.val();

    if (eventsObject) {
      return Object.keys(eventsObject).map((key) => ({
        key,
        ...eventsObject[key],
      }));
    }

    return [];
  };

  const addEvent = (text, selectedDate, selectedMonth, selectedYear) => {
    const eventData = {
      text: text,
      date: `${selectedYear}-${selectedMonth}-${selectedDate}`,
    };
    push(ref(db, path), eventData);
  };

  const removeEvent = (id) => {
    remove(ref(db, `${path}/${id}`));
  };

  const getEventByKey = async (id) => {
    if (!id) {
      return null;
    }

    const snapshot = await get(ref(db, `${path}/${id}`));
    return snapshot.val() || null;
  };

  const updateEvent = async (eventId, newTextValue) => {
    const eventPath = `${path}/${eventId}`;
    const updates = { text: newTextValue };
    
    try {
      await update(ref(db, eventPath), updates);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating event:", error);
    }
  };

  return {
    updateEvent,
    getEventByKey,
    removeEvent,
    addEvent,
    getEvents,
  };
};
```

I tried manually entering the path for update.

I changed the update in different ways.

Comment: Imagine having a *specific* problem, arriving here to Stack Overflow, and all the question titles being "*Idk why this code doesn't work*". Please [edit] and improve the title.